# Regex for matching spaces not preceded by commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert a string like this:

```
tag, tag2, longer tag, tag3
```

to:

```
tag, tag2, longer-tag, tag3
```

To make this short, I need to replace spaces not preceded by commas with hyphens, and **I need to do this in Javascript**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work

```
var re = new RegExp("([^,\s])\s+" "g");
var result = tagString.replace(re, "$1-");
```

Edit: Updated after Blixt's observation.

Comment: I'm accepting this one because it's the first one that worked. Can't believe I forgot the $1…

Comment: As suggested below you can use \s instead of space as well if you want to match tabs etc, but I took it quite literally to be spaces :)

Comment: Do consider that a comma followed by two or more commas will prefix the tag with -: `abc,<space><space>def` becomes `abc, -def`  What you want is `/([^,\s])\s+/g` with a replacement of `"$1-"`.

Answer (score 3):

`mystring.replace(/([^,])\s+/i "$1-");`  There's a better way to do it, but I can't ever remember the syntax

Comment: I believe you want the `g` flag, not the `i` flag. First of all, there are no characters to be made case insensitive, second of all, without the `g` flag it will only replace the first match. Also, you forgot a comma in there `=)`

Answer (score 1):

`[^,]` = Not a comma

**Edit** Sorry, didn't notice the replace before.  I've now updated my answer:

```
var exp = new RegExp("([^,]) ");
tags = tags.replace(exp, "$1-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.replace(/([^,]) /, '$1-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't seem to support negative lookbehinds, so you have to use something like this (modified from [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)):

```
var output = 'tag, tag2, longer tag, tag3'.replace(/(,)?t/g, function($0, $1){
    return $1 ? $0 : '-';
});
```

Comment: I didn't know you could put a "." after a string literal in javascript. That's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`[^,]` - The first character is not comma, the second character is space and it searches for that kind of string

Comment: sorry, this may be not in javascript

Answer (score -2):

```
([a-zA-Z] ){1,}
```

Maybe? Not tested. something like that.