# Regex to match urls but not urls in hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to wrap any url that is in some text and turn it into a hyperlink... but I do not want to wrap a url that is already wrapped by a hyperlink.

For example:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com">Go To Twitter</a>
here is a url http://anotherurl.com
```

The following code:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
<a href="<a href='http://twitter.com/twitter'>http://twitter.com/twitter</a>">@BIR</a>
<a href="http://anotherurl.com">http://anotherurl.com</a>
```

**How can I modify the regex to exclude already hyperlinked urls?**

Thanks

Answer:

The new method is:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
  var exp = /(?:^|[^"'])((ftp|http|https|file):\/\/[\S]+(\b|$))/gi
  return text.replace(exp, " <a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

The above code functions as required.  I modified the regex from a link in the comments because it contained a bug where it would include the full stop, it now excludes any full stops that come after a full url.

Comment: You should not use a regex to parse html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2177142/615754). And [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038910/regex-to-find-urls-not-in-tags?rq=1). Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2641582/615754).

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks nnnnnn.  I did search this morning but clearly my search phrases didn't match with anything useful.  Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: You're welcome. I found those by scanning down through the list of "Related" topics on the bottom right of this page...

Comment: With this: `(?:^|[^"'])` I think you just need `[^"']` and remove the grouping. No need to detect if it's the start of a string as there won't be any any other characters there, surely? Also, this would still detect someone putting an href in the text of anchor tags?

Answer (score 3):

Since [javascript doesn't seem to support negative look-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277583/1503784), you will have to trick it by using a replace function.
Capture the `href` (maybe you should also also consider `src`) :

```
function repl(text) {
  var exp = /((href|src)=["']|)(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(exp, function() {
    return  arguments[1] ? 
            arguments[0] : 
            "<a href=\"" + arguments[3] + "\">" + arguments[3] + "</a>"
  });
}
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VGVhv/)

**EDIT**

A "better" version which will only replace links in actual text nodes:

```
function repl(node) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i;
  var nodes=node.childNodes;
  for (var i=0, m=nodes.length; i<m; i++){
    var n=nodes[i];
    if (n.nodeType==n.TEXT_NODE) {
      var g=n.textContent.match(exp);
      while(g) {
        var idx=n.textContent.indexOf(g[0]);
        var pre=n.textContent.substring(0,idx);
        var t=document.createTextNode(pre);
        var a=document.createElement("a");
        a.href=g[0];
        a.innerText=g[0];
        n.textContent = n.textContent.substring(idx+g[0].length);
        n.parentElement.insertBefore(t,n);
        n.parentElement.insertBefore(a,n);
        g=n.textContent.match(exp);
      }
    }
    else {
      repl(n);
    }
  }
}

var r=repl(document.getElementById("t"))
```

​
See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mAJkL/)

Comment: Real nice answer.  I found another function, but up one for the great answer