# Make text into links outside of <a> tags only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my issue. I made a function that resolves links in javascript, but the use-case I'm stuck with is that there may already be HTML in posts with links.

Users can not post true HTML, but moderators and administrators can, meaning I need to handle both cases.

Here's an example of your typical user post HTML:

```
<div class="teaser">
    This is just your normal post http://google.com some other stuff
</div>
```

And administrator/moderator:

```
<div class="teaser">
    <b>
        <a href="http://test.com/who.html" target="_blank">THIS LINK</a>
    </b>
    <a href="http://test.com/who.html" target="_blank"><br></a><br>
    Supplemental reading: <a href="http://test.com/who.html" target="_blank">Link again</a>
</div>
```

Normally, I'd use something like

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"); 
}

c.not('a').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(html));
});
```

But this causes links to be parsed which exist inside of the href property. I need to be able to create links only when they are outside of  tags, and it needs to be through all children as you'll notice that  is the first child in a mod/admin post (if they so choose).

Mods and admins can put basically any HTML they desire in their posts, so the  tag could be anywhere in the post hierarchy which is not at all consistent.

I could just not parse links on admin or mod posts, but sometimes some mods and admins use the proper HTML tags, and sometimes they don't, which is why I'd like to know the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863847/regex-to-match-urls-but-not-urls-in-hyperlinks) it seems.

```
    filterTeaserLinkContent: function(data) {
        var exp = /\b((https?|ftps?|about|bitcoin|git|irc[s6]?):(\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/|magnet:\?(dn|x[lts]|as|kt|mt|tr)=)([^\s()<>]+|\([^\s()<>]+\))+(\([^\s()<>]+\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])/g;

        var nodes = data[0].childNodes;

        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var n = nodes[i];

            if(n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE || n.nodeName == 'BR') {
                var g = n.textContent.match(exp);

                while(g) {
                    var idx=n.textContent.indexOf(g[0]);
                    var pre=n.textContent.substring(0,idx);
                    var a=document.createElement("a");

                    if (!/^[a-z][\w-]+:/.test(g[0])) {
                        a.href = "http://" + g[0];
                    } else {
                        a.href = g[0];
                    }

                    a.innerText = g[0];
                    n.textContent = n.textContent.substring(idx+g[0].length);
                    n.parentElement.insertBefore(a,n);
                    g=n.textContent.match(exp);
                }
            } else {
                Board.filterTeaserLinkContent($(n));
            }
        }
    },

    filterTeaserContent: function(data) {
        // Jam into <div> so we can play with it
        var c = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');

        // Remove <wbr> tag which breaks links
        c.find('wbr').each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        // Re-parse the HTML after removing <wbr> or else the text nodes won't be joined
        c = $('<div>' + c.html() + '</div>');

        // I actually forget what this does, but fuck it. Shit.
        c.not("div, s, span, a").each(function() {
            var content = $(this).contents();
            $(this).replaceWith(content);
        });

        Board.filterTeaserLinkContent(c);

        // Remove images in post preview because they don't need to be here...
        c.find('img').each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        // Simplify line breaks
        return c.html().replace(/<br ?\/?><br ?\/?>/g, "<br>");
    },
```

This is for use in the [4chan API](https://github.com/4chan/4chan-API) in case anyone was curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var exp = /^(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
$('.teaser').each(function() {
    var i, words;
    $this = $(this);
    words = $this.html().split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (exp.test(words[i])) {
            words[i] = words[i].replace(exp, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
        }
    }
    $this.html(words.join(' '));
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/ywdf4/2/)**

Comment: Not working it seems (really doesn't address the problem I mentioned anyway), the error also exists in your fiddle.

Comment: Make sure you have removed your old `js code` `c.not('a').each(function() {` I have added a demo link

Comment: That isn't the issue. Press the "Do Linkification" button in your code then check the "THIS LINK" link below it. It breaks the link because it tries to parse the link in the href property, and ends up like this: <a href="<a href='http://test.com/who.html' target='_blank'>http://test.com/who.html</a>" target="_blank">THIS LINK</a>

Comment: That does work a lot better it seems, but it also seems to be missing some links now. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5F86G/1/ Maybe it would work better if I checked for href=" or href=' before attempting to parse